# Can't see some classes of CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-4

I'm developing my first application for CRM 2011. 
I've imported all .dll necessary for development.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages;
```

but when I call some simple classes like "Annotation", "Letter" , "Email", 
the visual studio doesn't detect these classes.

Has anybody knows why?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the tool CrmSvcUtil that comes with the SDK in order to generate your strongly typed classes.

[Create Early Bound Entity Classes with the Code Generation Tool (CrmSvcUtil.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327844.aspx)